# my canvas edit when hover another item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas

(check in Chrome only)

```js
$(function() {
   var Fire  = function(){

 this.canvas   = document.getElementById('fire');
 this.ctx    = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 this.canvas.height  = window.innerHeight;
 this.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;

 this.aFires   = [];
 this.aSpark   = [];
 this.aSpark2   = [];



 this.mouse = {
  x : this.canvas.width * .5,
  y : this.canvas.height * .75,
 }



 this.init();

}
Fire.prototype.init = function()
{
 
 //this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.updateMouse.bind( this ), false);

}
Fire.prototype.run = function(){
 
 this.update();
 this.draw();

 if( this.bRuning )
  requestAnimationFrame( this.run.bind( this ) );

}
Fire.prototype.start = function(){

 this.bRuning = true;
 this.run();

}
Fire.prototype.update = function(){

 this.aFires.push( new Flame( this.mouse ) );
 this.aSpark.push( new Spark( this.mouse ) );
 this.aSpark2.push( new Spark( this.mouse ) );



 for (var i = this.aFires.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aFires[i].alive )
   this.aFires[i].update();
  else
   this.aFires.splice( i, 1 );

 }

 for (var i = this.aSpark.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aSpark[i].alive )
   this.aSpark[i].update();
  else
   this.aSpark.splice( i, 1 );

 }


 for (var i = this.aSpark2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aSpark2[i].alive )
   this.aSpark2[i].update();
  else
   this.aSpark2.splice( i, 1 );

 }

}

Fire.prototype.draw = function(){

 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba( 15, 5, 2, 1 )";
 this.ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 
 this.grd = this.ctx.createRadialGradient( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y - 200,200,this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y - 100,0 );
 this.grd.addColorStop(0,"rgb( 15, 5, 2 )");
 this.grd.addColorStop(1,"rgb(30, 10, 2 )");
 this.ctx.beginPath();
 this.ctx.arc( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y - 100, 200, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 this.ctx.fillStyle= this.grd;
 this.ctx.fill(); 



 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";//or lighter or soft-light

 for (var i = this.aFires.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  this.aFires[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }

 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "soft-light";//"soft-light";//"color-dodge";

 for (var i = this.aSpark.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  
  if( ( i % 2 ) === 0 )
   this.aSpark[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }


 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";//"soft-light";//"color-dodge";

 for (var i = this.aSpark2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  this.aSpark2[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }


}







// Flame
var Flame = function( mouse ){

 this.cx = mouse.x;
 this.cy = mouse.y;
 this.x = rand( this.cx - 600, this.cx + 600);
 this.y = rand( this.cy - -200, this.cy + 5);
 this.vy = rand( 1, 3 );
 this.vx = rand( -1, 1 );
 this.r = rand( 20, 30 );
 this.life = rand( 3, 6 );
 this.alive = true;
 this.c = {

  h : Math.floor( rand( 2, 40) ),
  s : 1000,
  l : rand( 80, 100 ),
  a : 0,
  ta : rand( 0.8, 0.9 )

 }


}
Flame.prototype.update = function()
{

 this.y -= this.vy;
 this.vy += 0.05;


 this.x += this.vx;

 if( this.x < this.cx )
  this.vx += 0.1;
 else
  this.vx -= 0.1;




 if(  this.r > 0 )
  this.r -= 0.1;
 
 if(  this.r <= 0 )
  this.r = 0;



 this.life -= 0.15;

 if( this.life <= 0 ){

  this.c.a -= 0.05;

  if( this.c.a <= 0 )
   this.alive = false;

 }else if( this.life > 0 && this.c.a < this.c.ta ){

  this.c.a += .08;

 }

}
Flame.prototype.draw = function( ctx ){

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.r * 3, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 ctx.fillStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + (this.c.a/20) + ")";
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 ctx.fillStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + this.c.a + ")";
 ctx.fill();

}







// Spark
var Spark = function( mouse ){

 this.cx = mouse.x;
 this.cy = mouse.y;
 this.x = rand( this.cx -600, this.cx + 600);
 this.y = rand( this.cy - -200, this.cy + 5);
 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;
  <!-- Edit Value -->
 this.vy = rand( 1, 3 );
 this.vx = rand( -4, 4 );
 this.r = rand( 0, 1 );
 this.life = rand( 4, 5 );
 this.alive = true;
 this.c = {

  h : Math.floor( rand( 2, 40) ),
  s : 100,
  l : rand( 40, 100 ),
  a : rand( 0.8, 0.9 )

 }

}
Spark.prototype.update = function()
{

 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;

 this.y -= this.vy;
 this.x += this.vx;

 if( this.x < this.cx )
  this.vx += 0.2;
 else
  this.vx -= 0.2;

 this.vy += 0.08;
 this.life -= 0.1;

 if( this.life <= 0 ){

  this.c.a -= 0.05;

  if( this.c.a <= 0 )
   this.alive = false;

 }

}
Spark.prototype.draw = function( ctx ){

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo( this.lx , this.ly);
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + (this.c.a / 2) + ")";
 ctx.lineWidth = this.r * 2;
 ctx.lineCap = 'round';
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo( this.lx , this.ly);
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + this.c.a + ")";
 ctx.lineWidth = this.r;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

}

rand = function( min, max ){ return Math.random() * ( max - min) + min; };
onresize = function () { oCanvas.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; oCanvas.canvas.height = window.innerHeight; };



var oCanvas;
init = function()
{

 oCanvas = new Fire();
 oCanvas.start();

}


window.onload = init;

  });
```

```css
h1
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
float:right;
width:100%;
color:#fff;
}
#fire
{
 position:fixed;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fire"></canvas>
<h1>Hover Me!</h1>
```

I want to change the amount of canvas every time the Hover Me! is hoverd.

For example, this value is this.vy = rand (1, 3); To this value this.vy = rand (1, 30); When the hover changes.

Another thing to note is why the Mozilla browser is extremely difficult to execute and the colors in the Internet Explorer are not supported.

please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by crash? is there an error message? Look at the javascript / dev console.

Comment: In chrome I can, you have 18 errors in console: Uncaught TypeError: b.className.replace is not a function

Comment: Wow how did you do, my computer warmed up, and i saw what did you say when I open your page on firefox your background animation works very slowly and my cpu got high speed hence i didnt check what is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, edit your question so that we may help.  Specifically, you need to include all relevant code and/or error messages **within the body of the question** so that if the **link** disappears, the question will still be valid and useful. The easier you make it for us to know the question, the better your chances of receiving an answer. Cheers!

Comment: topic is edited